# How can I write a ToDhall instance for a ByteString, in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, dhall

So I have a simple data structure that has some `ByteString`s. I want to serialize these into Dhall files. However, I apparently can't just automatically derive `ToDhall`, since there's no instance for `ToDhall`. How do I write that?

```hs
data WordBounds = WordBounds { zipFile :: Prelude.FilePath
                             , start :: BS.ByteString
                             , end :: BS.ByteString
                             } deriving (Show, Generic, ToDhall)
```

I've tried `instance ToDhall BS.ByteString` and I think I'm getting closer, but I still don't quite understand what the syntax of `instance` is trying to do, and/or how to get it to work with Dhall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation, it looks like you could do something like this:

```
instance ToDhall ByteString where
    injectWith = contramap unpack . injectWith
```

This uses the two existing instances for `ToDhall`:

```
instance ToDhall Word8
instance ToDhall a => ToDhall [a]
```

...so the `injectWith` on the RHS of the equation is for `[Word8]`, not a recursive call to the one for `ByteString`. It also uses

```
instance Contravariant Encoder
```

to convert an `Encoder [Word8]` to an `Encoder ByteString`.

That said, this will be an orphan instance. Most of the community would recommend that you do not do that. Alternatives include creating a `newtype`, as in

```
newtype Jonathan'sByteString = Jonathan'sByteString ByteString
```

and writing instances for that instead, or simply writing

```
jonathan'sInjectWith :: InputNormalizer -> Encoder ByteString
jonathan'sInjectWith = contramap unpack . injectWith
```

and then using that in a hand-written `instance ToDhall WordBounds`.